# A milestone reached: 10000 questions

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics

As the [Questions page](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions) shows, the site now has over 10000 questions!

The graph of questions per month shows that the rate at which questions are asked is also growing, with obvious seasonal fluctuations. ([Source](https://data.stackexchange.com/bicycles/query/683594/questions-per-month-with-deleted#graph))

Congratulations!

[image: questions per month]